# Change Zoom Canon SDK

Tags: .net, vb.net

Does anyone know how to change the zoom using Canon SDK?

I need to make two pictures with different zoom.

I found in EDSDKTypes.vb but not how to do it :

```
' EVF IMAGE DATA Properties
Public Const kEdsPropID_Evf_Zoom As Integer = &H507
Public Const kEdsPropID_Evf_ZoomPosition As Integer = &H508
```

Comment: And what's `EDSDKTypes.vb` you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand very well, my English is poor.    Public Enum EdsEvfZoom
        kEdsEvfZoom_Fit = 1
        kEdsEvfZoom_x5 = 5
        kEdsEvfZoom_x10 = 10
    End Enum

Comment: For those who don't know what this means `I found in EDSDKTypes.vb but not how to do it`, please explain.